# On Linux Plesk server Laravel storage link appears as broken link

Tags: linux, laravel

In a Centos LInux (plesk) build I'm running a Laravel app.
In the root I run `php artisan storage:link`
Like it normally does it creates a storage directory in my public folder.
However in this server instance the storage link is broken.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

As you can see it appears in a black shade with red type.  Aka a broken link in Linux.
Any idea why this is happening?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAHs9.png

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by creating a manual symlink with an absolute path

```
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/storage /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/public
```